# What is the adjective for low libido (woman)

Tags: word-request

It starts with letter **f** I think, but I can't recall the word.

Anybody?

Comment: Not really sure why this has been closed. It seems better than many single word requests. OP has indicated why they think a word exists, but given the nature of the word, it may not appear in bilingual dictionaries.  This seems on topic.

Comment: @JamesK I agree. I immediately understood the request and came up with an answer (which was the same one you provided), so there is really no confusion here. +1 to reopen.

Answer (score 6):

The word you are thinking of is "frigid".

This also means "very cold", and its use to mean "very cold" is generally uncontroversial.

> The house was frigid and ice had formed on the inside of the windows.

You should not use it to describe a woman. It is seen as extremely sexist.

Comment: While it's polarizing, the term *is* used very frequently in this sense, and not even (historically) meant to be sexist. In fact, I've heard it used to describe men too. Having said that, it shouldn't be used casually; you should be familiar with social contexts and know exactly what you're doing if you use it in this context.